# fragment doesn't replace when I click on bottomnavigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

why when i click the item navigationview fragment not replace in content.

```
navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.navigation_home) {
      fragment = new HomeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.navigation_dashboard) {
      fragment = new PopularFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.navigation_notifications) {
      fragment = new FeaturedFragment();
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
  }

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

*Use the below code in android.support.v4*

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
DemoFragment w1 = new DemoFragment();
ft.addToBackStack("");
ft.replace(R.id.listFragment, w1);
ft.commit();
```